# titan make unique vertex based on property key

Tags: unique, vertex, gremlin, titan

I want to create a vertexs that do not have duplicate property, e.g., name

I followed the page https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices

However, it does not work for me

```
gremlin>g.makeType().name('dom').unique(OUT).dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).makePropertyKey()
==>v[36028797018965714]
gremlin> u2 = g.addVertex([dom:'def.com'])
==>v[480020]
gremlin> u2 = g.addVertex([dom:'def.com'])
==>v[480024]
```

Can I just have one vertext created for the same dom property?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your type as `unique(BOTH)`.  You can read more about types [here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview#unique-types).

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/titan')
==>titangraph[local:/tmp/titan]
gremlin> g.makeType().name('dom').unique(BOTH).dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).makePropertyKey()
==>v[36028797018963978]
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
gremlin> u2 = g.addVertex([dom:'def.com'])
==>v[4]
gremlin> u2 = g.addVertex([dom:'def.com'])
The given value is already used as a property and the property key is defined as in-unique
Display stack trace? [yN] n
gremlin>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for helping me out.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, I want to put it in groovy script, so that I can run batch insert. I encouner errors, like 'javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given value is already used as a property and the property key is defined as in-unique', then the program exits. How can I run the script without exception?

Comment: To me it seem that the type we defined is doing just what it should.  That error is precisely the one you should expect to see if you add more than one "dom" properties with the same value.  Make sure you check for existence of "dom" before you addVertex. If it is already there then don't add that vertex again.

Comment: I want to use titan distributively. If I check the existence of the vertex before insertion, then it may encounter race condition issue. Also, I want to know what is the fastest way to check existence, I use g.V.has('dom', 'def.com'), which is very expensive.

Comment: If two transactions in separate threads try to insert the same vertex, you should get a transaction failure.  `g.V('dom','def.com')` and `g.V.has('dom','def.com')` compile to a graph query (https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/blob/2214c60c690862c1792ad602b6f4720f20df90ce/gremlin-java/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/java/GremlinPipeline.java#L223) from a gremlin perspective assuming an index is involved.  Since you've index `dom` you should not end up with a vertex scan.

Comment: Thanks for help.  I am thinking to use try{}catch{} in groovy script to avoid java exception exist, err_dup='java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given value is already used as a property and the property key is defined as in-unique'

try {
    v1 = g.addVertex([doma:'test4.com'])
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
{
    if(e ==~ err_dup)
    {
        v1 = g.V.has('doma', 'test4.com').next()
    }
}  What do you think?

Comment: That makes sense.  I would further recommend additional handling that retries the transaction on a `TitanException` with exponential backoff.

Comment: I don't have any specific code I can share, but maybe you can get some ideas from the exponential backoff policy in the google http java client: https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/ExponentialBackoff  The main point is to retry the transaction if it fails as the result of a `TitanExeption`.  Start with a simple for loop that tries the transaction X number of times before it fails for good, with a maybe a Y milliseconds of wait before each retry.  Once that is working, refactor into something more robust (i.e. exponential backoff).